# Customization: Specific DE for specific User

Tags: users, customization, desktop-environments

Is it possible to setup?

Suppose, I have two users: `Home` and `Work`.

For `Home` I want to use `GNOME Shell` or `KDE` a beautiful DE. (Or something else)

For `Work` I want to use `LXDE` or `MATE` as fastest DE. (and also more energy efficient)

Maybe this can be done in other way.
I don't know these ways, please, advise.

Answer (score 2):

In 12.04 and 12.10:
First install these desktop environments from Ubuntu Software Center, then reboot. In Unity Greeter (login screen), click on the Ubuntu icon. You can choose which DE to use. Your choice will be stored for each user, so you have to do it only once.